# How to create dropdown list from a ENUM in razor pages with different name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, dropdown, razor-pages

I am using razor pages
Enum:

```
public enum CustomersFilter
{
    Unassigned,
    Unverified_Mobile = 1,
    Unverified_Email = 2,
    Both = 3,
}
```

payload:

```
public class UnverifiedCustomersPayload
{
    public CustomersFilter Status { get; set; } = CustomersFilter.Unassigned;
    public IEnumerable<CustomersFilter> FilterableStatus { get; }

    public UnverifiedCustomersPayload()
    {
        FilterableStatus = Enum
                            .GetValues(typeof(CustomersFilter))
                            .Cast<CustomersFilter>()
                            .Where(o => o > CustomersFilter.Unassigned);

    }

public UnverifiedCustomersPayload Filters { get; set; }
```

HTML:

```
                        <select class="form-control"
                                asp-for="Filters.Status"
                                asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Filters.FilterableStatus))">
                            <option value="0">None</option>
                        </select>
```

I am getting data and names but with names *Unverified_Email* and *Unverified_Mobile*

but I need them as **Mobile Unverified** and **Mobile Unverified**

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Add [Display Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute?view=net-6.0) to them:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public enum CustomersFilter
{
    Unassigned,
    [Display(Name="Unverified Mobile")]
    Unverified_Mobile = 1,
    [Display(Name="Unverified Email")]
    Unverified_Email = 2,
    Both = 3,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will use the `Display` attribute then not necessary to define the `<option value="0">None</option>`. The `Unassigned` value already set to `0` value by default. Therefore it's necessary only add a description for it.

```cs
public enum CustomersFilter
{
    [Display(Name = "None")]
    Unassigned,
    [Display(Name = "Mobile Unverified")]
    Unverified_Mobile = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Email Unverified")]
    Unverified_Email = 2,
    [Display(Name = "Both")]
    Both = 3,
}

public class UnverifiedCustomersPayload
{
    public CustomersFilter Status { get; set; } = CustomersFilter.Unassigned;
}
```

The view part can be set as follow:

```
@using WebApp.Models
@model UnverifiedCustomersPayload

<select class="form-control"
        asp-for="Status"
        asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<CustomersFilter>()">
</select>
```

[The `GetEnumSelectList` method generates a `SelectList` object for an enum.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#enum-binding)

[image]